# Does MISRA C:2012 rule 21.1 contradict with C11?

Tags: c, misra

MISRA C:2012, Rule 21.1:

> `#define` and `#undef` shall not be used on a reserved identifier or reserved macro name.

However, C11 permits to define, for example, `__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__`.

Example:

```
#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1       /* violation of MISRA C:2012, rule 21.1 */
#include <stdio.h>
#ifdef __STDC_LIB_EXT1__
/* tmpfile_s is available */
#endif
```

Does it mean that rule 21.1 contradicts with C11?

---

UPD. Any MISRA-C compliant project cannot use Annex K. This is because per MISRA C:2012 Amendment 2:

> Other than defining `__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__` to '0', the **facilities of Annex K** (Bounds-checking interfaces) **shall not be used**.

Comment: It's normal for coding standards to be more restrictive than what the basic language allows. This isn't a contradiction.

Comment: The single purpose of MISRA and other such standards is to forbid what the base language standard allows.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. LOL. You have reduced it's purpose dramatically :) Although I am tending to agree when it comes to MISRA specifically.

Comment: @EugeneSh. well if restricting the language is not the purpose, then it is the means to achieve the purpose. Either way a coding standard doesn't do anything else. It simply cannot do anything else.

Comment: Is this question perhaps misphrased? More specifically, shouldn't the question be whether MISRA contradicts *itself*, with regards to C11 Annex K? As in, Rule 21.1 blankets not using `#define` with reserved macros, but the amendment permits `#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 0`? Because otherwise, of course MIRSA will *contradict* [*sic*] the C11 standard by limiting access to inherent features of the language.

Comment: @Barmar Yes, indeed. One example is Rule 20.9, which requires for all identifiers used in the controlling expression of `#if` or `#elif` preprocessing directives to be `#define`’d before evaluation. However, the C standard does not require that, because "all remaining identifiers (including those lexically identical to keywords) are replaced with the pp-number 0" (C11, 6.10.1/4).

Comment: The point of coding standards like this is to force you to write "safer" code by limiting the features of the language that you use. E.g. you shouldn't depend on undefined macros being replaced with `0` by default -- initialize them explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The original MISRA-C:2012 only covers C90 and C99.

As you apparently found out yourself, the MISRA C:2012 AMD2 regarding C11 compatibility pretty much bans all prominent C11 features (Rule 1.4 AMD2.30), including the annex K bounds-checking interface.

I have absolutely no idea why anyone would want to `#define __STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__ 1` in general, let alone in a safety-related application. The bounds-checking interface has received a lot of critique even from inside the WG14 C committee. You shouldn't need a rule to tell you that it has no place inside a MISRA C application - common sense will get you very far.

As for rule 21.1, the rationale is that people shouldn't run off to create their own magic wrappers with surprising behavior around standard library functions etc. Like `#define strcpy(dst, src) strcpy(src, dst)` or similar macro madness that people who like to invent their own "local garage standard" macro languages might come up with.

Comment: Re: "lot of critique even from inside the WG14 C committee": yes, I'm aware of it. See, for example, [1](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1967.htm), [2](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2336.pdf), [3](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1962.htm), [4](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2307.pdf) (search for N1962).

Comment: As an extension of this answer, Rule 1.4 restricts use of new features that MISRA have concerns about, but have not yet produced fuller guidance for.  The next increment will add guidance for some of these new features, and the blanket (Rule 1.4) restriction relaxed.

Comment: @Andrew Will there be support for C17/C18? The concern against using `_Generic` was, as I understood it, that different compilers treated qualified types passed to `_Generic` differently. This was fixed in C17 and the type passed to `_Generic` now has the qualifiers removed: "The type of the controlling expression is the type of the expression as if it had undergone an lvalue conversion". So now it ought to be well-defined and there are many situations where `_Generic` can be used to increase program safety.

Comment: The next update is (hopefully) being released to coincide with Embedded World in June.  This will (again, hopefully) include guidance on `_Generic`.  Rule 1.4 in AMD2 is a placeholder, to allow C11/C18 features that had no concerns, while we catch up on those that need further guidance... and as new guidance is added, the Rule 1.4 list will shorten.

Comment: PS: If you are coming to EW in Nuremburg in June, do come and say "Hi!"

Answer (score 2):

Notwithstanding the specifics of your intended use of `__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__`, Rule 20.1 seeks to prevent accidental or deliberate (re)definition of reserved macros.

Any **intended** (re)definition is permitted by means of a deviation - which requires the user to justify what they are doing.

If you **really** want to use Annex K (and @Lundin already addresses the reasons why you probably shouldn't), you can do so - by deviating Rule 20.1 to redefine `__STDC_WANT_LIB_EXT1__` and Rule 1.4 to revoke the blanket restriction currently in place. This deviation will require **you** to show that you understand the problems with Annex K, and what **you** are doing to prevent the dubious behaviours.

As a footnote, the current position of the MISRA C WG is that the restriction on Annex K is likely to remain, at least until wg14 agree on a path forward.

*Disclaimer: See profile for my affiliation*